# Replace Text with DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use the DocumentApp service to replace text in a document but it is not working.

My code is:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{{1}}", "This is a number");
doc.saveAndClose();
```

It works when I add with alphanumeric string but not digits.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason you are using braces? The script is treating `{{1}}` as a regular expression which matches `{}` i.e. 1 instance of braces. Your current code will find and replace `{}` in the doc body.

If you need to replace {{1}} then change:

`body.replaceText("{{1}}", "This is a number");`

to

`body.replaceText("{{1*}}*", "This is a number");`

or don't use braces at all and use chevrons instead `<<1>>`