# How do I create a google appscript which copies an existing Google Doc then replaces certain text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

Based on the code below I was expecting the AppScript to copy my document, then replace all instances of {{resultID}} with 12345. I am getting an error.

```
function generateReport() {
    var doc = DriveApp.getFileById('asdfasdfasdfasdf').makeCopy('Document 1');
    var newDocID = doc.getId();
    var body = newDoc.getBody();
    body.newReplaceAllTextRequest('{{resultID}}','12345');
}
```

I tried the script above, while it successfully creates a copy of the document, it does not replace the text.

Comment: Where do you get the code? What is the textual error message?

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion: use `replaceText()`

`newReplaceAllTextRequest()` requires the use of Docs V1 API. It's much simpler to use the existing `replaceText()` method instead.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
function generateReport() {
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById('doc_id').makeCopy('Document 1');
  var newDocID = doc.getId();
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID).getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{resultID}}', '12345');
}
```

### Reference:

- [replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the new doc with the DocumentApp first, so you can edit it.
According [to this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408628/4103426) it is better to use <> instead of {{XXXX}

```
     function generateReport() {


            var originalFile = DriveApp.getFileById('*****FILE_ID_HERE*********')
            var copiedFile = originalFile.makeCopy('Document 1');
            var newDocID = copiedFile.getId();

            // Open de Document using DocumentApp now, so we can edit it.
            var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID)
            var body = newDoc.getBody();

            // I've replaced the {{ by <<, because that can cause some troubles... The script might think you are trying to use a regex.  
            body.replaceText('<<resultID>>','12345');
    
            // Save and close the doc. (otherwise, changes won't be visible immediatly...)
            newDoc.saveAndClose()
        }
```